# hibernate session.get gives proxy object

Tags: hibernate, proxy

Does hibernate session.get gives proxy object. Based on the below link I see that get always returns a real object and not a proxy object. But today I saw a strange behavior where the get was giving a proxy object if the proxy object already exists in the cache otherwise a real object. My understanding was even if the object exists or doesn't exist in the cache session.get would always give a real object and not a proxy object. Can some one explain on this.

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/different-between-session-get-and-session-load

Comment: What's your question? You've tested it, and the test showed that get() does return a proxy if the proxy is already in the cache. So, do you want us to tell you that your test is correct? It is. The linked page is wrong. BTW, load() will also return a "real" entity instance if it's already in the cache.

Comment: How did you checked it's returning a proxy?

Comment: I am not saying that the test is correct. I am trying to understand the behavior of session.get in case if the object already exists in the cache. Would it return the object in cache or it returns  a real object.

Comment: @Vaishu13 you've got a test proving that it does return the object in the cache. What do you want more?

Comment: If a proxy object exists in the Session cache will it return a proxy object. If the object exists in the cache then if get call doesn't hit the database then what is the difference between a load vs get. Even load tries to get an object from cache.

Comment: get() will hit the database if the proxy is not initialized yet (and thus initialize the proxy), to make sure that the entity does exist. But it will still return the proxy.

Comment: So it means hibernate session.get wouldn't always return a real object but could return a proxy object as well.

Comment: @Vaishu13, can you show the code that confirms your findings?

Comment: Chaitanya, as the actual code is little complex below is the brief description of what i was trying to do.    for(Long id : Arrays.asList(1,2)) {
 B b = (B) serviceA.getA(id); 
 List<X> list = serviceToReturnX     

}

Comment: First one is a service call which again makes DAO call in which session.get call is made. So when this is called with 1 it returns the actual object. But when it is called with 2 it was returning a proxy object because of which it was throwing classcastexception

Comment: and the reason why it was returning a proxy object when called with 2 is another service call is made after the first service call which returns List<X> where X and A has a bidirectional relationship and A has one to many relationship with X. So in the List<X> the A objects are proxied objects and instance of A for id 2 exists as proxy object in the returned list.